# validation rule to limit field to small range of numbers?

Tags: validation-rule

I'm trying to make a simple validation but its not firing right.

What I'm trying to do:

If Days record type, this should always be 1. For Hours record type, this should always be a number between 1-24.

Right now I have the following but I was able to save a value of "27" successfully which should have caused the VR to fire:/

`IF( Work_Statement__r.RecordType.Name = "Days", Unit_of_Time__c = 1, Unit_of_Time__c < 24)`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation rules, when they evaluate as `true` cause the configured error to be displayed and the record to not save.

Thus, your conditions are backwards

```
IF( Work_Statement__r.RecordType.Name = "Days", 
   Unit_of_Time__c <> 1,  /* must be 1 */
   (Unit_of_Time__c >= 24 || Unit_of_Time__c < 0)) /* must be 0..23 */
```

Comment: had to slightly modify it, `(Unit_of_Time__c > 24 || Unit_of_Time__c < 1 )` but thanks for explaining this, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Your validation rule will be like below.

```
 OR(AND(Work_Statement__r.RecordType.Name = "Days",Unit_of_Time__c <> 1),
    AND(Work_Statement__r.RecordType.Name ="Hours",OR(Unit_of_Time__c<1,Unit_of_Time__c>24))
   )
```

AND

> Returns a TRUE response if all values are true; returns a FALSE
> response if one or more values are false.
>
> Use the && (AND) function as an alternative to the operator.
>
> Use
>
> AND(logical1,logical2,...) and replace logical1,logical2,... with the
> values that you want evaluated.

OR

> Determines if expressions are true or false. Returns TRUE if any
> expression is true. Returns FALSE if all expressions are false.
>
> Use this function as an alternative to the operator || (OR)
>
> Use
>
> OR(logical1, logical2...) and replace any number of logical references
> with the expressions you want evaluated.